# how to send data to a php page using a table + button

Tags: php, html

I'm simulating an e-commerce shopping list and I need to pass data from a php page to another. I'm using a table with 5 columns, last will be blank cause its where I'm putting the shop-buttons

```
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">name</th>
<th scope="col">model</th>
<th scope="col">capacity</th>
<th scope="col"></th>
```

Now I'm cycling through my database and for every row as an associative array, i'm using

```
<tr scope="row">
    <td>{$var[id]}</td>
    <td>{$var[name]}</td>
    <td>{$var[model]}</td>
    <td>{$var[capacity]}</td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now for the fun part: how do I get these buttons to retrieve all data from that row and send it to another page (first a blank debug page, then a page that will actually make a query to insert that transaction into the DB).

If possible, I would avoid using JS. Thanks

Comment: What about a form with inputs you echo your values into?

Comment: Change your button to an anchor tag that calls the URL of the other page and pass the data to be inserted as part of the URL (anchor tag ... href= etc).

Comment: Even better might be cookies. Just using the table to show the items.

Answer (score 0):

if what you are trying to achieve is to pass your data to another page by clicking the button in each of the table rows. Then you can simply add a get parameter to your button link and run your query where the id is equal to your get parameter. for instance you link would look like this:

example.com?id={$var[id]}
in the new page you can now run your query as:

select id from table where id = $_GET['id'];

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Bootstrap and if so, you could replace the button with the following:

```
<?php
echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" role=\"button\" href=\"add_to_cart.php?id={$var["id"]}\">Buy</a>";
```

Comment: but how is href passing that value to the next page? inside the get array? later on i will need to re-use that id, i shall keep track of it using session, for instance.

Comment: Yes, the ID is put into the $_GET array and you can retrieve it on the next page (add_to_cart.php in this case) by $_GET["id"].

Comment: can't manage to make it work.. i'm not used to this inline syntax, $_GET is not "getting" any value..